How to start MainActivity after SplashScreen?
I want to run my app on devices below android 12. The app will have a splash screen, the app can't use splash screen api becuase it does not work sufficiently in devices below android 12. How to correctly start MainActivity after showing SplashScreen?
SplashActivity
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity: ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AudioAppTheme {
                SplashScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SplashScreen(){
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        delay(2000)
        startActivity(Intent(this@SplashScreen,MainActivity::class.java))
    }
}

Manifest file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/spotify"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/spotify"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AudioApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MySplash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity" android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>

I read multiple article but didn't find a good solution.

Why bother using multiple activities when you're using Jetpack Compose? Use a single activity so that instead of starting another activity after the Splash delay is done navigate to the next screen using the navigation component library.

delay(2000) Please don't do splash screens this way. It makes your app 2 seconds slower to start for absolutely no reason.

Pass the Context to Composables: You can pass the Context from the Activity to the Composable function.
Modified Code:
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AudioAppTheme {
                // Pass the context to SplashScreen
                SplashScreen(context = this)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun SplashScreen(context: Context) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        delay(2000)
        // Use the passed context to start the MainActivity
        context.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
        // Optionally finish the SplashActivity if you don't want to keep it in the back stack
        if (context is Activity) {
            context.finish()
        }
    }
}


delay(2000) - I know it's from the question, but please don't do splash screens this way. It makes the app 2 seconds slower to start for absolutely no reason.

I think so 2 secs okay for the app start splash screen, @RyanM

I work with teams who would happily spend many dozens of engineering hours to reduce app launch times by half a second.  People want apps that launch quickly.
They wouldn't dream of intentionally making their app feel slower.  And note - this isn't 2 seconds of total app launch time.  This is 2 seconds after the app is already fully loaded.

@RaynM so how you suggest implementing splash screen, because splash screen occurs in most apps today.

You can do something like this:
SplashScreen.kt
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        delay(3000L) // 3 seconds delay
        navController.navigate("home_screen")
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Blue),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Splash Screen",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    }
}

HomeScreen.kt
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Home Screen",
            color = Color.Black,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    }
}

Then, in MainActivity.kt you can handle the navigation between them
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyApp() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "splash_screen") {
        composable("splash_screen") { SplashScreen(navController) }
        composable("home_screen") { HomeScreen() }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MyApp()
}


delay(3000) - I know the question does a similar thing (though you made it longer, which is worse), but please don't do splash screens this way. It makes the app 3 seconds slower to start for absolutely no reason.
